# Vector of Vectors as Input to a java progam gives casting issues from String args[] to Vector type

Tags: java, vector, casting

Input arguments that should be given to the program is Vector of Vectors like the one below,

```
[['red','black','blue'],['white','grey','yellow'],['white','orange']]
```

Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Vector<Vector<String>> v1= new Vector<Vector<String>>();
     v1.add((Vector<String>) Arrays.asList((args[0])));
}
```

gives runtime error as `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector`

please suggest how to cast this String as Vector.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast a `List<String>` as a `Vector<String>`, which will fail at runtime.

Since `Vector` is obsolete, I would advise you use a `List<List<String>>` instead.

**Edit**

If you **really** have to use `Vector`s, you cannot cast, but you can use the following idiom:

```
Vector<String> argsVector = new Vector<String>();
argsVector.add(args[0]);
v1.add(argsVector);
```

Comment: Can we cast String args[] to Vector by any means. Using Vector is in the requirement.